# Stripe redirect to my SPA loses all state

Tags: redirect, single-page-application, stripe-payments

After submitting the Stripe payment form (hosted on their server), a redirect happens to my React SPA that launched it. It reloads the entire SPA, losing all state. I'm using React Router and the return address I've set up is a particular Route. How can I prevent it from losing all state?

The same problem happens when clicking the Cancel in the form, or hitting the back button.

Sure I can store the state on the server before launching the payments page, and then retrieving it later, but that's a lot of extra work.

I think this must be a common problem with SPAs, but I haven't found an easy solution.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue right now. Did you end up using local storage?

Comment: @RamanSB I'm using SessionStorage, as I want the information to be removed when the user closes the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your state is only in memory, I would expect to lose it. To keep it around, you need to save it *somewhere* to be reloaded when the user comes back to your site. Local storage is a good option.

If you are using redux for state management, for example, you can use `redux-persist` to save & load your redux store in local storage.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

Comment: Local storage would work, but in my case I ended up using session storage. I'm not using redux, but that persist feature is something to keep in mind.